# html works in chrome but not ie

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

My mini website works well in chrome, but not IE. Can someone tell me why it doesn't?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

   <title>Steves Homepage</title>

    <style>

#left {

    float:left;
    margin:0;

    padding:0;

    width:33%;

;

}

#right {

    float:right;

    margin:0;

    padding:0;

    width:33%;

}

#middle {

    float:left;
    width:33%;
}

#wrapper {

    width:100%;

}

li {

    list-style-type: none;

}

          </style>

    </head>


    <body>



<div id="wrapper">


    <div id="left">


        <ul>


            <li><b>Useful Docs</b></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Passwords.txt">Passwords</a>
</li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Server Naming Convention.txt">Server Naming Convention</a></li>

            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Numbers.txt">Common Phone Numbers</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/GPO.txt">GPO</a></li>

            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Useful Emails.txt">Useful Emails</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/F5 Notes.one">F5 Notes</a></li>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <b>Spreadsheets</b>
            <li><a href="file://///birmingham-nas/nsd/Engineering/Official_Structure/DSL_details/EMEA_DSL_Details.xls">DSL Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="file://///birmingham-nas/nsd/Engineering/Official_Structure/EMEA-IP_ADDR_ALLOCATION_LISTS/EMEA-WAN-&-Remote_Site_Subnets-Loopbacks.xls">IP Spreadsheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Telephone Numbers.xls">Phone Numbers</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="middle">

        <ul>

            <li><b>Configurations</b></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/MRV Config/MRV Config.txt">MRV Config</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/MRV Config/MRV Lines.txt">MRV Lines</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/DMVPN Config.txt">DMVPN Config</a>
</li>

            <li><a href="file://///birmingham-nas/nsd/Engineering/Official_Structure/Remote Office Standards/New-PDU-Setup.doc">PDU</a>
</li>

            <li><a href="file://///birmingham-nas/nsd/Engineering/Official_Structure/Remote Office Standards/UPS-Setup.doc">UPS</a>
</li>

            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <b>Websites</b>
            <li><a href="http://emea-orion">Orion</a>
</li>

            <li><a href="http://rhitime/planview">Timesheets</a>
</li>

            <li><a href="http://itportal/sites/ProdSvcs/ChangeSvcs/default.aspx">Change Management</a>
</li>

            <li><a href="http://onyx/oep_win/powerpage/application_main.asp?profileid=1&profilename=OEP%20User&ucfsafemode=0">Onyx</a>
</li>

            <li><a href="https://ra.rhi.net/">Juniper VPN</a></li>



        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="right">

        <ul>

            <li><b>How To Guides</b>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Meeting Rooms.txt">Meeting Rooms</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Activations/Masergy Activations.txt">Activations</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Engineer Dispatch Guide.txt">Engineer Dispatch Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Temperature Issues.txt">Temperature Issues</a></li>
            <li><a href="file://///birmingham-nas/nsd/Engineering/Official_Structure/Remote Office Standards/Comms standards/RHI_EMEA_Comms_Standards_V5.2_Type_1.pdf">Comms Standards Normal</a></li>
            <li><a href="file://///birmingham-nas/nsd/Engineering/Official_Structure/Remote Office Standards/Comms standards/RHI_EMEA_Comms_Standards_V5.2_Type_2.pdf">Comms Standards Large</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Orion Back End.txt">Orion Back End</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Orion Front End.txt">Orion Front End</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/New Site Deployment Checklist.txt">New Site Deployment Checklist</a></li>

            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <b>Useful Links</b>
            <li><a href="file://///birmingham-nas/nsd">Birmingham NAS</a></li>
            <li><a href="file://///C:/Users/stegar06/AppData/Roaming/VanDyke/Config">Secure CRT Files</a></li>
            <li><a href="file://///birmingham-nas/nsd/Engineering/Official_Structure/Technical Content & Software/Software/Cisco IOS">IOS Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://emea-pac:8083/proxy.pac">Proxy Pac File</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

In IE the display is fine, but when you click on any of the links it doesn't direct you to the files. I don't understand why, because they must be referenced correctly because chrome loads the links.

Comment: This thing here is invalid `file://///birmingham-nas/nsd/Engineering/Official_Structure/Remote Office Standards/UPS-Setup.doc`

Comment: The problem might be the use of `file:///` URIs, support for them can be a bit inconsistent. I'd avoid them in favour of relative URIs.

Answer (score 2):

you can use relative address with respective to the current folder. like

For file in similar folder

```
<a href ="my_file.html">Link</a>
```

and folder which is one up lavel

```
<a href="../another_folder/my_file.html"></a>
```

benifite to this is if you change your project your given absolute file address dont work but relative will work fine